# XQuery: How to know if there are doublets?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have XML file there is `<a>` and `<b>` for each `element`

I want to write a query using XQuery to return True or False

there is  an element called `<element>`.

each `<element>` has 2 element in it `<a>`and`<b>`.

Return False : 
if there is any `<a>` has the same value as another `<a>` in another element && there `<b>`'s value are different

otherwise True : 
 `<a>` values are differnt in each element
or there is similarity but there `<b>` values are different

for example

```
<root>
<element>
   <a>ttt</a>
   <b>tttsame</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>ttt</a>
   <b>tttsame</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a/>
   <b>value</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>rrr</a>
   <b>rrrvalue</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>mmm</a>
   <b>rrrvalue</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>mmm</a>
   <b>rrrvalue</b>
</element>
</root>
```

This one should be okay 
should return true

```
<root>
<element>
   <a>ttt</a>
   <b>ttt value</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>ttt</a>
   <b>ttrdiff</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a/>
   <b>value</b>
</element>
<element>
   <a>mmm</a>
   <b>rrrvalue</b>
</element> 
</root>
```

shoudn't be accepted because ttt has two different values
should return false

Comment: This is still unclear. What's the difference between the "good" XML and the "bad" XML?

Comment: There is still no clear relation between input XML and output XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple XPath 2.0**:

```
empty(
        (for $parentA-Dubled in /*/*[a = following-sibling::*/a]
           return
             empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                                        [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
        )
        [not(.)]
      )
```

---

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "empty(
            (for $parentA-Dubled in /*/*[a = following-sibling::*/a]
              return
                empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                                         [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
            )
             [not(.)]
          )
     "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document, it evaluates the XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation**.

When applied on the first provided XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
true
```

When applied on the second provided XML document, again the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
false
```

---

**Explanation**:

This sub-expression:

```
(for $parentA-Dubled in /*/*[a = following-sibling::*/a]
               return
                 empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                          [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
```

evaluates to a sequence of boolean values: `true()` / `false()`

`true()` is returned when this is true:

```
empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                          [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
```

This means that `true()` is returned for every occasion when there is an `$parentA-Dubled/a` that has no other `a` (a child of a following sibling of `$parentA-Dubled` with the same value as `$parentA-Dubled/a` but the value of its `b` sibling is different than the value of `$parentA-Dubled/b`.

**To summarize**: `true()` is returned when for **all** `a` elements with the same value, their `b` siblings also have (all `b` s) the same value

Then when is the case when `false()` is returned?

Returning `false()` means that `empty()` returned `false()` -- that is, there exists at least one occasion of two `a` elements that have the same value, but their `b` siblings have different values.

Thus, the sub-expression above returns a sequence such as:

`true(), true(), true(), ..., true()`  -- all values are `true()`

or

`true(), true(), true(), ..., false), ..., true()` -- at least one of the values is `false()`

The original problem requires us to return `true()` in the first case and to return `false()` in the second case.

This is easy to express as:

`empty($booleanSequence[. eq false()])`  -- and this is equivalent to the shorter:

`empty($booleanSequence[not(.)])`

Now, we just need to substitute in the above expression `$booleanSequence` with the first sub-expression that we analyzed above:

```
(for $parentA-Dubled in /*/*[a = following-sibling::*/a]
               return
                 empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                          [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
```

Thus we obtain the complete XPath expression that solves the original problem:

```
empty(
        (for $parentA-Dubled in /*/*[a = following-sibling::*/a]
           return
             empty($parentA-Dubled/following-sibling::*
                                        [$parentA-Dubled/a eq a and $parentA-Dubled/b ne b])
        )
        [not(.)]
      )
```

Comment: Referring to the Simple Xpath 2.0 solution - well, it certainly works but my head is spinning trying to figure out why. Can you please show me how this voodoo works?

Comment: @JackFleeting: Thanks for your appreciation. I have added an explanation about the meaning of the XPath expression and its constituents.

Answer (score 2):

You could group on `a` and then check if there is more than one distinct `b` in any group, for instance with

```
not
(
    for $a-group in root/element
    group by $a := $a-group/a
    where tail(distinct-values($a-group/b))
    return $a-group
)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2r/0 and https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2r/1 has your two input samples.

As for how it works, the question asks to return false "if there is any `<a>` has the same value as another `<a>` in another element && there `<b>`'s value are different".

To find `element` elements with the same `a` child element we can `group by $a := $a-group/a` in a `for $a-group in root/element` expression. The distinct or different `b` values in each group of `a`s with the same value are computed by `distinct-values($a-group/b)`, if there are at least two different `b` values then `tail(distinct-values($a-group/b))` contains at least one value, otherwise it is an empty sequence. This works as through XQuery 3's `group by` clause "In the post-grouping tuple generated for a given group, each non-grouping variable is bound to a sequence containing the concatenated values of that variable in all the pre-grouping tuples that were assigned to that group" (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by) so that after the `group by $a := $a-group/a` clause the variable `$a-group` is bound to a sequence of `element` elements with the same grouping key based on the `a` child element.

So the complete `for .. group by .. where .. return` selects the groups of `element` elements with the same `a` value where there are at least two different/distinct `b` values.

As the requirement is to "return false" if any such groups exist the `not()` function is applied to implement that condition as the boolean value of a non-empty sequence is true and the `not(..)` then gives false if there are any elements meeting the condition expressed in the `for` selection.

Comment: Can you please explain how this expression works to achieve OP's requirements?

Comment: I think I get it now; thanks. It's really depressing to realize once in a while how much more there is to learn...

Comment: @JackFleeting: Why XQuery 3 when this can be done more simply with an XPath 2.0 expression?   :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this XQuery code to get only one distinct item of `<a>` (The corresponding `<b>` value is not specified; here, the first element is chosen):

```
let $file := doc("input.xml")/root,
    $vals := distinct-values($file/element/a) return
  <root>
    {for $i in $vals return $file/element[a=$i][1]}
  </root>
```

**Its result is:**

```
<root>
    <element>
        <a>ttt</a>
        <b>ttt value</b>
    </element>
    <element>
        <a/>
        <b>value</b>
    </element>
    <element>
        <a>rrr</a>
        <b>rrrvalue</b>
    </element>
    <element>
        <a>mmm</a>
        <b>rrrvalue</b>
    </element>
</root>
```

Comment: this won't work because I need to know for each <a> tag is there a duplicated value or only one and then get true or false

Comment: You can do this by checking the count of items for each distinct-value: Replace the `for...` with `for $i in $vals return 
    if (count($file/element[a=$i]) gt 1) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'`.

Comment: it didn't work I have same tag with different values and it returns true
this one looks like only data which is not duplicated will return false

my case 
I need it to return false only if the same value of <a> have different value of <b>

Comment: Please read my comments above. Your question does not form a [mcve]. It is contradictory. Because of that, I do not know how your desired output would look like. Edit your question to make it consistent containing the actual output and the desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You still have two `<a>` `ttt` elements with the same `<b>` values `tttsame` in your input XML and two different `<b>` output values `ttt value` and `ttrdiff` in your output XML. I do not know of any transformation that can achieve that (within reasonable bounds). And there is still no [mcve].

Comment: this not input and output example . two different XML file
First one should return True , 
second one should return False